# Isomorphism between group and dual

Tags: abstract-algebra

How does one prove that a group is isomorphic to its dual (character group)? I’ve seen it mentioned in a book but wondered how one might prove this. For $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is easy and I could also prove it for $\mathbb{Z}_n$ with some effort, but I see mo way this could generalize

Comment: Use the structure theorem for abelian groups and the fact that the dual commutes with finite direct sums.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not isomorphic, see here:

[$G$ be a finite group and $G'$ be its commutator subgroup and $\widehat G$ be the character group of $G$ ; then $G/G' \cong \widehat G$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401589/g-be-a-finite-group-and-g-be-its-commutator-subgroup-and-widehat-g-be-th?noredirect=1&lq=1)

If $G$ is abelian, then we have $\widehat{G}\cong G$. The proof is given above.